# Need the decimal to save and show three places

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line of code in c# but i it always resets the textbox back to the format 0.00, how can i make it so that it keeps the format 0.000 ?.

```
NewYorkTax = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewYorkTax.Text);
 //converts it but with 0.00, I need 0.000 or 7.861 etc..
```

SIDE NOTE:
NewYorkTax is of type Decimal, I need to keep this variable.. any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: That line of code doesn't appear to be modifying any properties of txtNewYorkTax (which I presume is the textbox), only reading its Text property. You need to identify the code that is setting the value of txtNewYorkTax.Text.

Comment: decimal type cannot distinguish b/w 0.00 and 0.000. You'll have to take care of string formatting whenever you display the value.

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the 3 zeros in the decimal variable?  I.e., decimal NewYorkTax = 0.000?

Comment: not only zeros any number like 8.678

Comment: why the negative vote, if I am asking is because i dont know... if you need more information just ask and i will provide it.. easy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to format the string in your textbox:

```
decimal NewYorkTax = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewYorkTax.Text);

//... code that is doing stuff with the decimal value ...

txtNewYorkTax.Text = String.Format("{0:0.000}", NewYorkTax);
```

**EDIT:** Clarified the use of `String.Format`

**Second edit:** Regarding exceptions

Also bear in mind the risk of converting to decimal when taking in human input. Humans are error-prone creatures. :)

It helps to use `TryParse`, which `Decimal` supports:

```
decimal NewYorkTax;

if (Decimal.TryParse(txtNewYorkTax.Text, out NewYorkTax)) // Returns true on valid input, on top of converting your string to decimal.
{
    // ... code that is doing stuff with the decimal value ...

    txtNewYorkTax.Text = String.Format("{0:0.000}", NewYorkTax);
}
else
{
    // do your error handling here.
}
```

Comment: this looks good but.. i have a variable of type Decimal called NewYorkTax, so i tried NewYorkTax = String.Format("{0:0.000}", Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewYorkTax.Text)); , but it gives an error that it can not convert string to decimal.. how can fix this and still be able to use my variable.. ?

Comment: You need to set your Text property of your TextBox with the formatted string. See my edit.

Comment: Note that `Convert.ToDecimal(string)` can throw exceptions... using a Masked Input Field can help to eliminate this by simply not allowing "invalid numbers".

Comment: @pst: That doesn't protect against individuals bypassing the fields directly and just posting the data. See my edit for a way to handle bad input server-side.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use like this..

```
NewYorkTax = Convert.ToDecimal(String.Format("{0:0.000}", Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewYorkTax.Text)));
```

Comment: Why... would you want to do this? To ensure you truncate decimal values to three decimal places? I don't think that's what the OP is asking for.